# Enery and power when we have trigonometric functions (Fourier transform)

Tags: signal, fourier

It is asked to evaluate the energy and power of the signal

$$x(t)=10\cos(100t+30°)-5\sin(220t-50°)$$

Since it is periodic, I need to find

$$\int _{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)|^2 dt \text{ and } \frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^T |x(t)|^2 dt$$

Where \$T\$ is the period of \$x(t)\$ (which is \$18\$). By Parseval's theorem, we know the energy is conserved when we do a Fourier transform and I was trying to use it (but I couldn't). What is the best way of evaluating those integrals?

Comment: seems like a maths question to me.

Comment: The best way would be to open a table of integrals and use it.

Comment: What sort of signal is it? Power, current, voltage?

Comment: If \$x(t)\$ is always real (no imaginary part), you can drop the absolute value signs because \$x^2(t)\$ will always be positive.

Answer (score 1):

For any periodic signal you get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^2dt=\infty$$

i.e. the integral does not converge, and, consequently, the energy is infinite. The power is finite and can be computed from the following formula (which differs from yours by a factor of \$\frac12\$):

$$\overline{x^2(t)}=\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T|x(t)|^2dt$$

Note that \$\cos^2 x=\frac12 (1+\cos(2x))\$ and \$\sin^2 x=\frac12 (1-\cos(2x))\$. So after integrating over one period, the terms with double frequency and also the cross-term cancel out. So you finally get for the power

$$\overline{x^2(t)}=10^2\cdot \frac12 + 5^2\cdot\frac12=62.5$$

Note that the actual value of \$T\$ is irrelevant. This is a good thing because the value you got is wrong.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that \$T\$ is irrelevant - the frequency of a sinusoidal function doesn't affect its power.